# Поместить код под EULA

Tags: header, text, лицензирование

Приведите примерный текст, который нужно добавить в начало файла с кодом, чтобы поместить его под стандартный **End User License Agreement.** Текст лицензии имеется, заголовок нужен на английском языке. Если не очевидно, открывать код не планирую, а для закрытой лицензии не могу найти хедер, никогда такого кода не писал и с ним не работал. Текст нужен просто для порядка и большей законности(есть сомнения, что без хедера конкретные файлы попадут под эту лицензию).

Comment: Вспомнил, что изучал примеры из Windows SDK. Он под EULA(так что соврал). Там вот такая строка: Copyright (c) 1991-1998, Microsoft Corp.  All rights reserved. Вроде бы её можно использовать, но всё равно жду пояснения, хватит ли этого, если код лицензии приложен к программе.

Comment: Написать можно что угодно в свободной форме. Хотя бы даже и "Написал этот файл Илья Иванов. Копировать хоть целиком, хоть по частям разрешаю только Василию Пупкину.". А дальше, если вдруг кто нарушит - будете доказывать в суде.